# Howto generate ECDSA SignatureValue for XML with python and cryptography (wsse)

Tags: python, xml-signature, wsse

I have a canonicalized XML with wsse (http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd) headers, `ds:Signature` and `ds:SignedInfo` elements (`xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"`). This XML is a SOAP request, and it needs to be signed.

I have already calculated the ECDSA digital signature of the signedinfo element, something like this:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, ec, rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import decode_dss_signature


assert isinstance(private_key, ec.EllipticCurvePrivateKey)
bin_signature = private_key.sign(signedinfo_c14n_xml_data, ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256()))
r, s = decode_dss_signature(bin_signature)
```

I need to put this into a `SignatureValue` element. I think that https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc4050/ describes how it should be calculated:

> The input to the ECDSA algorithm is the canonicalized representation of the dsig:SignedInfo element as specified in Section 3 of [XMLDSIG].
>
> The output of the ECDSA algorithm consists of a pair of integers usually referred by the pair (r, s).  The signature value (text value of element dsig:SignatureValue - see section 4.2 of [XMLDSIG]) consists of the base64 encoding of the concatenation of two octet-streams that respectively result from the octet-encoding of the values r and s.  This concatenation is described in section E3.1 of [IEEE1363].

I'm unable to figure out how it is done. I could not find section E3.1 of [IEEE1363].

**How to convert these `(r, s)` values (which are simple integer numbers) into a base64 encoded `SignatureValue`?**

I have a working example XML (generated by another program) and it generates something like this:

```xml
<ds:SignatureValue>I2K/43Hf1dPNnhWKy28dHftysnrqA8n9DG0Yzmafvr8vwHfV6lHt0MNC/JD77BkjMqdyr71p+ti4 u06c8va1CA==</ds:SignatureValue>
```

That program is written in Java, and it uses `org.apache.wss4j`. It actually works (the SOAP server accepts the signature.) The signature value seems to be a base64 value, but there is a space character inside. According to base64 specs, any characters outside of the base64 alphabet are to be ignored in base64-encoded data. So it is not an error to have a space there, but it is **really strange**.

Comment: Convert r and s into an unsigned, big endian byte array. r and s are each to be padded to their maximum size (size of the order of the generator point) with leading 0x00 values. Concatenate r and s and Base64 encode the data.